# Ready Function doesn't Get Value from Input After Page Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, frontend

I am having issue waiting on a DOM element to load. I am trying to get the value in an HTML input. Here are the 2 methods that I used but they both did not work:

Option 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var inputVal = $(".class-name tag-label");
         if (inputVal != undefined && inputVal.innerText != undefined && inputVal.innerText != ""){
                    //do something
               }
               else{
                    //not to do something
               }
    });
```

Option 2):

```
 $(".class-name tag-label").ready(function() {
        var inputVal = $(".class-name tag-label");
         if (inputVal != undefined && inputVal.innerText != undefined && inputVal.innerText != ""){
                    //do something
               }
               else{
                    //not to do something
               }
    });
```

However, after the page is loaded, and I do $(".class-name tag-label") and it's returning the proper element with a value in the console. Anything I did incorrectly?

Comment: Can you provide some HTML too? And what is it you are trying to achieve? Do you really want to get the starting value of a `<tag-label>` element directly after the page has loaded? Does such an element exist? Or do you want to get something a user might have entered after the page was loaded?

Comment: You could use document.find to find element which may load via ajax or created by javascript. Example `var inputVal = $(document).find('.class-name')`

Comment: @Tamin `$(".class-name")` is the same as `$(doument).find(".class-name")` no need for `$(document).find`

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() {` is the correct format.   The question is, how does your `.class-name tag-label` get loaded?  Sounds like it's not loaded with the original HTML, but loaded later, via javascript/ajax.  Please confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your comments. I realized that `document` was undefined, and was actually missing `windows.load`

```
window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
        var inputVal = $(".class-name tag-label");
        if (inputVal != undefined && inputVal.innerText != undefined && inputVal.innerText != ""){
           //do something
        }
        else{
          //not to do something
        }
   });
```

This works for me ^